# How to do refactoring this structure, if-else-if-else-if * 100

Tags: c++, design-patterns

There is some nasty legacy code.

```
std::string xxx = GetCommand(); // get "CommandX";
if (xxx == "Command1")
{
    return new Command1();
}
else if (xxx == "Command2")
{
    return new Command2();
}
...
else if (xxx == "Command100")
{
    return new Command100();
}
```

I want to improve this code structure.
There were too many comparison. So I put them to a map.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GetCommandCount(); ++i)
{
    // key is a command string
    // value is a function pointer which creates it's instance
    map.insert(command, a function pointer);
}

// then

ICommand* pCommand = map.getInstance(command);
```

But this way has to make additional function every time if new command comes.
Yes, the functions might be reasonable. But all the functions just be `return new CommandNNN();` I guess there is the way to remove the duplication.

How do you think?

Comment: Find the guy who wrote the code and shoot him! For once, be the psychopath that lives next door with a chainsaw!

Comment: I think a function per command sounds reasonable and readable. Does having all these functions create a problem for you, or is it simply that you don't like it?

Comment: Just be glad he didn't think "HEY I could use a macro to make this code cleaner!"

Comment: @Magnus I think so. But I think it's code duplication. I'm finding a way removing the duplication. And your answer is best way what I wanted, so far. I'm waiting some other idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since all the functions are `return new CommandNNN();`, you can use a template function:

```
template <class T>
CommandBase* createCommand() {
    return new T();
}
```

and bind to this function in your map:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair("Command1", &createCommand<Command1>));
map.insert(std::make_pair("Command2", &createCommand<Command2>));
map.insert(std::make_pair("Command3", &createCommand<Command3>));
```

This lets you avoid creating a new function for each command. However, there would still be some duplication in the `map.insert`-statements. This could be further reduced by using macros, if that's your cup of tea:

```
#define INSERT(cmd) map.insert(std::make_pair(#cmd, &createCommand<cmd>));

INSERT(Command1);
INSERT(Command2);
INSERT(Command3);

#undef INSERT
```

or

```
#define INSERT(n) map.insert(std::make_pair("Command" #n, &createCommand<Command ## n>));

INSERT(1);
INSERT(2);
INSERT(3);

#undef INSERT
```

I suspect that you can even get the preprocessor to do some counting for you, but that's outside of my domain.

---

Applying even more macros, as well as some global state, both of which are frowned upon by many, you can get even tighter coupling:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

class CommandBase {};

static std::map<std::string, CommandBase* (*)()> g_commandMap;

template <class C>
CommandBase* createCommand() {
    return new C();
}

class CommandRegistrer {
public:
    CommandRegistrer(const std::string& name, CommandBase* (*instantiator)()) {
        g_commandMap.insert(std::make_pair(name, instantiator));
    }
};

#define COMMAND_CLASS(n) \
    class Command##n; \
    CommandRegistrer g_commandRegistrer##n("Command" #n, createCommand<Command##n>); \
    class Command##n : public CommandBase

COMMAND_CLASS(1) { /* implementation here */ };
COMMAND_CLASS(2) { /* implementation here */ };

int main() {
    assert(g_commandMap.find("Command1") != g_commandMap.end());
}
```

Comment: +1 for "basic" template function, simpler and faster than lambdas (note, you could remove the `&` I think, function references would be implictly converted). Regarding the "counting": don't bother, it looks like an artifact example ;)

Comment: +1 for the use of macros to produce cleaner code. This technique has been ridiculized in the comments of the OP's question, but actually I think it can be useful sometimes.

Comment: @Magnus: Suppose, it's time to add `Command101`. I implemented class `Command101`, but forgot to add `INSERT(Command101);`. If compile error occurs, it would be better. But it cannot yet. Am I right? Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Benjamin: I've updated the answer. It now relies on global state.

Comment: You wrap the macro, to avoid a mistake! I really like your macros.

Comment: You can use boost preprocessor to automatically enummerate them.

Comment: @DeadMG: It would be fun to see that as well. Feel free to add another section to my answer if you feel like it. :)

Comment: @DeadMG: I want to see it too, interesting.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using C++11, you can use inline lambdas to do it so that everything is in one place:

```
class Object
{
};

class Command1 : public Object
{
};

// etc

typedef std::map<std::string, std::function<Object*()>> FunctionMap;
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::function<Object*()>> FunctionPair;

FunctionMap funcMap;
funcMap.insert(FunctionPair("Command1", []()
    {
        return new Command1();
    }));
```

Comment: You could even replace all the `insert` calls to populate the map with a huge initializer list, really moving the map creation to compile time, allowing the compiler to optimize even more :)

Comment: @rubenvb: map creating would happen at program startup, not at compile time, though. (Though a "static constructor" would be a neat concept for C++19!)

Comment: Kerrek: I don't see why a `const std::map` initialized in its constructor would have to be constructed at runtime. It could be a constant memory block of 1's and 0's embedded in the executable? Or at least in my mind it should be :). Are there any rules in the Standard preventing such an optimization? Isn't it similar to string literals? They are just embedded memory locations as well, no?

Comment: @rubenvb I think that would be allowed under the as-if rule. But don't expect to find many compilers out there implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a static array

```
static struct cmdthing {
    const char *cmd;
    void (*fun)();
} commands[] = {
    {..,..},
    {..,..},
    ...
};

for(const cmdthing *p=commands;p<commands+sizeof(commands)/sizeof(*commands);++p)
    if(!strcmp(p->cmd,cmd)) return (*(p->fun))();
```

Or something like that?

Comment: why not `std::vector` and `std::find`?

Comment: Isn't that what you did here?

Comment: No, it's not. First, I didn't postpone till runtime what I could do at compile time. Second, I avoided bringing in structures that has nothing to do with the simple task. Third, the whole logic takes just a few lines and they are not scattered across your codebase.

Comment: You can use `std::find` with arrays.

Comment: `std::find` is okay here, though it doesn't simplify things, you'd need to use lambda if available or invent your own function for comparison and it still will be slower and not any clearer. The only thing you gain is that you can claim that you've used the algorithm, which is not an immediate object of programming. You don't have to be of my opinion, though, there's always more that one way to write code.

Comment: Well, I think the code would be clearer, but yeah that's personal opinion. However, I doubt your claims and `std::find` would be slower.

Comment: `std::find` wouldn't be slower if we didn't have to provide a comparator. Of course, depending on how critical it is the slowdown may be safely ignored. My experience suggest that is's going to be about the same speed with optimization on and about half as fast with optimization off (with gcc). But I do not see how we can come to agreement regarding clarity - what's clear for one is murky for the other and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your map as private member of your factory like:

```
CommandFactory{
 private:
  std::map< std::string, ICommand*> m_commands;
 public:
  CommandFactory();
  ICommand* getInstance()const;
  virtual ~CommandFactory();
};
```

In the constructor register all your actions like:

```
CommandFactory(){
  m_commands.insert( std::pair< std::string, ICommand*>("commandName", new Command) );
}
```

ICommand is an interface so make a virtual method invoke()

```
class ICommand{
  public:
    ICommand();
    virtual bool invoke()=0;
    virtual ~ICommand();
};
```

But normally an simple factory could be anough.

Comment: The issue here is that you're creating the command whether or not it is being called or not.  This may or may not be a problem.

Comment: I think that if you make a new action you will use it otherwise why to keep the dead code??

Comment: I'm not sure what these command objects of the askers actually contain, but what if they create things such as network resources to perform?  What if they can be instantiated in different ways with different parameters?  If we have them all created at the start, how do we pass extra information to them?  It's better to create them when needed, imho.

Comment: All the objects will be instantiated with the CommandFactory instantiation so you can pass all the arguments needed for command generation in your CommandFactory constructor. Of course the better way is to generate the object when it is needed and normally this is the standard way to do this with the factory method or abstract factory. In my opinion the code which a asker posted at the first time was ok and this is a standard way to implement the mapping with a factory design pattern.

Comment: The factory design pattern doesn't specify that everything is created at start up.  It provides a method *to* create something given a name, type or some such identifier.  Like I said, these commands might allocate things you don't want hanging around.  I think your factory suggestion is fine, I just think it should be a factory of `ICommandCreator`, whose job it is, is to create your `ICommand` instances.

Comment: This is the abstract factory I mentioned before. Anyway in my opinion an simple factory is anough in this case. Have a nice day, thank you ;).

Comment: It is not an abstract Factory because you lack a factory base type, but it is a pretty standard way of making commands during deserialization where resources shoudn't be taken during constructionn.  You would even have a function to parse the stream for its parameters because the command should have best knowledge about its parameters.

Comment: If you want to make new commands on request, so they can have state, then you need a clone() function per command.  These turn out to be the create functions that the OP wants to avoid

Answer (score 1):

just parse the string to return an int then go through a switch. that should be fast and small. the `case`s can be generated quite easily, if needed. sample's pretty obvious:

```
int ToCommandID(const std::string& CommandX) { evaluate and return X as an int }

Command* NewCommand() {
    const std::string xxx(GetCommand()); // get "CommandX";
    const int commandID(ToCommandID(xxx));
    switch (commandID) {
        case 1 : return new Command1();
        case 2 : return new Command2();
        case 3 : return new Command3();
        case 4 : return new Command4();
        case 5 : return new Command5();
        case 6 : return new Command6();
        case 7 : return new Command7();
        case 8 : return new Command8();
        case 9 : return new Command9();
        case 10 : return new Command10();
        case 11 : return new Command11();
        case 12 : return new Command12();
        case 13 : return new Command13();
        case 14 : return new Command14();
        ...
        default : {
            assert(0 && "oh no!");
...
```

sorry, no fancy language features today TT. Sure, you could run this through a macro and make it fewer characters, or you could mark it as generated code and be done in 2 minutes.